# Reference for a course in Calculus

Tags: calculus, reference-request

I am requested to offer a course in Calculus. The syllabus contains the notion of Curvature (of a curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$), convexity, singular point, node, cusps, volume, area, reduction formulae etc. Can anyone suggest me any recent reference book/notes for this? Thanks in advance for any help or suggestion.

Comment: Applications...to what? Physics (astronomy, movement of bodies on a plane, surfaces or volumes...), economy, chemistry, biology...?

Comment: I don't completely understand: the "syllabus" you mention looks like a syllabus of a course in calculus I, *not* a course for applications of calculus...Anyway, you can check almost any physics-oriented book for applications in physics. Try for example Anton-Bivens-Davis' "Calculus". At the end of each section there are meny exercises, some with applications. Or try any book in mechanics or electricity for more...

Comment: Well, I meant a mathematical book, which describe those written notions with a lots of (mathematical) examples.

Comment: Becuase of the confusion created, I deleted the term 'Application'. Hope it's okay now.

Comment: I'm not sure what "I am requested to offer a B.Sc. course in Calculus." means. Are you being asked to teach a course? And you're hoping to find a good text for your students to use?

Comment: @JohnHughes Yes, I'm asked to teach a course, and I'm looking for a text not only for the students, but for mine as well. Can you help me with anything?

Comment: I think part of the confusion shown in the comments arises from trying to imagine why you don't just use any of the several books previously used in past decades where you're at, or what you used as a student, or books you or your friends or your colleagues have on their bookshelves, or any of a number of other situations I can imagine (not all of which might apply to you, of course). That is, there seems to be a huge amount of context missing, and the lack of this context makes it difficult to understand exactly what situation you are in, which is needed to offer any kind of useful advice.

Answer (score 3):

Try any one of

- **Applications of Calculus : Theory and Problems** (Academic Publishers) by Sitansu Bandyopadhyay & Sunil Kumar Maity
- **Differential calculus for beginners** (Macmillan, 1896) by Joseph Edwards
- **Differential calculus** (U.N.Dhur & Sons Private Limited) by B. C. Das and B. N. Mukherjee